# extracting a message from the grid by finding the co-ordinates using a cipher text

Tags: python

I have created a decoder where it can decrypt a cipher message and finds the original message by mapping the letters from the cipher to the grid , so for every two letters, it maps to a letter in the grid (by column then row)

```
EE,DC,FC,AC,BD,AB,CD,FD

    A    B    C    D    E    F
A ['O', '9', 'L', 'K', '4', 'N']
B ['H', 'V', 'U', 'B', 'P', 'X']
C ['D', 'W', '3', 'E', '6', 'A']
D ['5', 'T', 'I', '8', 'J', 'S']
E ['Z', 'M', 'C', 'Q', 'R', '7']
F ['1', 'Y', 'G', '2', '0', 'F']
```

in this case the message is 'readthis'(EE=r,DC=e, etc...)
from here this message needs to be put into a string list where i can then print it on the IDE console

first i made a randomised 6x6 matrix

```
gridlayout= []
list1 = list(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
for i in range(6):
    grid2=[]
    for j in range(6):
        thing = random.choice(list1)
        grid2.append(thing)
        list1.remove(thing)
     gridlayout.append(grid2)
    list2=list(messagetoencode)
    print("  A    B    C    D    E    F")
    for i in  gridlayout:
       print(i)
```

my code so far...

```
for char in decode:
    for row in range(0,6,1):
        for column in range(0,6,1):
            if(gridLayout[row][column] == char):
                finaltext+=char[row][column]
```

im not sure if this is on the right lines or not

Comment: I hope your not using for any real work hahha :-)

Comment: only for purposes of learning and understanding in order to further increase my knowledge on python, sometimes everyone needs a little help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution.  Build a dict table mapping the two letter keys to the one letter values

```
keyz=['A','B','C','D','E','F']

matrix = [ 
['O', '9', 'L', 'K', '4', 'N'],
['H', 'V', 'U', 'B', 'P', 'X'],
['D', 'W', '3', 'E', '6', 'A'],
['5', 'T', 'I', '8', 'J', 'S'],
['Z', 'M', 'C', 'Q', 'R', '7'],
['1', 'Y', 'G', '2', '0', 'F']]

rkc=0
decode={}
for row in matrix:
    y=keyz[rkc]
    ckc=0
    rkc = rkc+1
    for col in row:
        x=keyz[ckc]
        decode[x+y]=col
        ckc = ckc + 1

for letter in ["EE","DC","FC","AC","BD","AB","CD","FD"]:
    print decode[letter],

print
```

edit: Here is a full version with encode, decode and a random matrix

```
import string
import random
gridlayout= []
messagetoencode="readthis"
list1 = list(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
for i in range(6):
    grid2=[]
    for j in range(6):
        thing = random.choice(list1)
        grid2.append(thing)
        list1.remove(thing)
    gridlayout.append(grid2)
    list2=list(messagetoencode)
print("  A    B    C    D    E    F")
for l in gridlayout:
    print l

keyz=['A','B','C','D','E','F']

rkc=0
decode={}
encode={}
for row in gridlayout:
    y=keyz[rkc]
    ckc=0
    rkc = rkc+1
    for col in row:
        x=keyz[ckc]
        decode[x+y]=col
        encode[col]=x+y
        ckc = ckc + 1

obfuse=[]

for letter in messagetoencode:
    obfuse.append(encode[letter.upper()])

print "obfuse is ", obfuse

for letter in obfuse:
    print decode[letter],

print
```

Comment: i forgot to mention i initially made a randomised 6X6 matrix , i've changed my code above to show this

Comment: The code I suggested will work if you change my variable "matrix" to your variable "gridlayout" from the randomizer